# Scrapy save URLs titles in text file

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi I have following Scrapy code and I want to save all titles of URLs provided in one file but it saves only title of last("url3").

```
    from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
    from kirt.items import KirtItem 

    class KirtSpider(BaseSpider):

        name = "spider-name"

        allowed_domains = ["url1","url2","url3"]

        start_urls = ["url1","url2","url3"]


    def parse(self,response):

        sel = Selector(response)
        title = str(sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract())

        with open('alltitles.txt','w') as f:
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(title)
```

Comment: Check your indentation -- I'm guessing that you want the `with....` clause indented a stop, yes?

Comment: Sorry did not get you. oh got you. let me check

Comment: @bgporter I mistyped here only. my source file was fine and now corrected here too. Any idea how I can save all titles rather than only one... I am feeling that it is saving title each time and updating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here, in two different ways:

```
    with open('alltitles.txt','w') as f:
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(title)
```

Opening a file with mode `'w'` not only opens the file, but if there's already a file with that name, it deletes it first. You should instead open the file with mode `'a'`, which appends new lines to an existing file if one exists.

Past that,  though, you also call `f.seek(0)`, which rewinds the file write pointer back to the beginning of the file and would make it overwrite the current file contents. That chunk of code wants to be more like:

```
    with open('alltitles.txt','a') as f:
        # write out the title and add a newline.
        f.write(title + "\n")
```

Comment: Bingo thanks, One thing I also did forget to mention that First we also to convert title into string.